# How can I check if a value is in a certain place of a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a 2D Array:
`int[][] family = new int[10][];`
and I then add the number two to it with `family[0][0] = 2`

How do I check if the value 2 is in the first element of the array or not?

I've tried `if (family[0][0] == 2){return true;}` but when I run the program it just skips over it.

Full code:

````
        int[][] family = new int[1000000][];
        Random rn = new Random();
        Family f = new Family();
        
        int answer = rn.nextInt(2) + 1;

        try {
            family[0][0] = answer;
        

        if (family[0][0] == 1) {
            System.out.println();
        }
            
        
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {}```
````

Comment: Can you post the whole code? It will be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: I've added to the question

Comment: what is this code supposed to do ? You are assigning a random int (1 or 2)  to (0,0) position then checking it for only 1.

Comment: After looking at the code, I can say that it will always end up executing the catch block because you haven't initialized columns for family array so you can't put anything at position [0][0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared length of column during 2D array initialization or before assigning value to `family[0][0]`, so either you can do it like `int[][] family = new int[2][2];` thus having an array of 2 rows and 2 columns or you can create dynamic number of columns for each row(say row 0) using `family[0] = new int[2];`.

The dynamic approach is shown in the code below:

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] family = new int[10][0]; 
        family[0] = new int[2]; //Initializing Row 0 with 2 Columns
        family[0][0] = 2; //Adding 2 to family array at position [0,0]
        System.out.println(check(family));
    }
    
    static boolean check (int[][] family)
    {
        if (family[0][0] == 2)
        return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```